# how to store answers of a survey in a python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, store, survey

I have to do a survey and then save this answers of many students in a dataframe. I tried to store answers in a list but doesn't work because when I tried to save the answers in the dataframe I get the dataframe with multiple answers in the same column instead of many rows as the number of answers.
this is my survey

```
sex=input('your sex: ')
sex_list.append(sex)
country=input('where do you come from?: ')
country_list.append(country)
sport=input('have you ever play sport?: ')
sport_list.append(sport)
if sport=='no':
reason_no_sport=input('why didnt you play sport?:')
reason_no_sport_list.append(reason_no_sport)
else:
reason_no_sport=np.nan
reason_no_sport_list.append(reason_no_sport)
football=input('have you ever play football?: ')
football_list.append(football)
basket=input('have you ever play basket?: ')
basket_list.append(basket)
swimming=input('have you ever play swimming?: ')
swimming_list.append(swimming)
```

this are the list

```
  sex_list=[]
  country_list=[]
  sport_list=[]
  reason_no_sport_list=[]
  football_list=[]
  basket_list=[]
  swimming_list=[]
```

this is the dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"sex": [sex_list],
               "country": [country_list],
               "sport":[sport_list],
              "why didnt you play sport?": [reason_no_sport_list],
              "football":[football_list],
              "basket":[basket_list],
              "swimming":[swimming_list]})
```

this is the result is something like

```
sex=`[male, female]`
country= `[usa, england]`
```

Comment: Hello! you should add the relevant part of the code, i.e. where you try to convert the list into a dataframe. Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57692009/edit) your post to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I offer you a possible solution to your problem. I create lists and in them I add the answers:

```
sex=[]
country=[]
sport=[]
reason_no_sport=[]
football=[]
basket=[]
swimming=[]
interview='doing'
while interview.upper()=='DOING':
    if((input('Can you answer some questions?: ')).upper()=='YES'):
        sex.append(input('your sex: '))
        country.append(input('where do you come from?: '))
        s=input('have you ever play sport?: ')
        sport.append(s)
        if s.upper() == 'NO': 
            reason_no_sport.append(input('why didnt you play sport?:'))
            football.append(np.nan)
            basket.append(np.nan)
            swimming.append(np.nan)
        else: 
            reason_no_sport.append(np.nan)
            football.append(input('have you ever play football?: '))
            basket.append(input('have you ever play basket?: '))
            swimming.append(input('have you ever play swimming?: '))
    if((input('Do you want to do another interview?: ')).upper()=='YES'):
         continue
    else:
        break
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['sex']=sex
df['country']=country
df['sport']=sport
df['reason_no_sport']=reason_no_sport
df['football']=football
df['basket']=basket
df
```

> Output example:

```
Can you answer some questions?: yes
your sex: m
where do you come from?: spain
have you ever play sport?: no
why didnt you play sport?:i don't like it
Do you want to do another interview?: yes
Can you answer some questions?: no
Do you want to do another interview?: yes
Can you answer some questions?: yes
your sex: f
where do you come from?: portugal
have you ever play sport?: yes
have you ever play football?: yes
have you ever play basket?: no
have you ever play swimming?: yes
Do you want to do another interview?: no
```

---

```
    sex country  sport  reason_no_sport football    basket  swimming
0   m   spain    no     i don't like it NaN         NaN     NaN
1   f   portugal yes    NaN             yes         no      yes
```

You could also create a list (`name`) and ask for the name and use this as a `DataFrame` index:

`name=[]`

`name.append(input('what is your name: '))`

`df.reindex(name)`

Answer (score 0):

> I get the dataframe with multiple answers in the same column instead of many rows as the number of answers

To solve this, it's enough to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"sex": sex_list,
          "country": country_list,
          "sport": sport_list,
          "why didnt you play sport?": reason_no_sport_list,
          "football": football_list,
          "basket": basket_list,
          "swimming": swimming_list})
```

Since they are already list, you don't need to wrap them into another list by using another pair of square brackets.

#### Building the dataframe correctly

However be careful: you probably want in your final dataframe a row for each person who answered the survey. Lists do not remember this, since in your survey you don't add elements to all the list each time (you have `if else`).

To fix this, you have two ways.

1. Add an element to each list each time. Edit your `if else` statements so that when the user does not answer a question, a `None` value to the corresponding list is added, as done in [@lostCode answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692604/10426037).
2. Do not use lists at all. Create an empty dataframe from the beginning, and store the answers in it as new rows.
   For example, you can create the empty dataframe doing:

   ```
   column_names = ["sex","country","sport",
         "reason_no_sport_list","football","basket","swimming"]

   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
   ```

   Then each time you propose your survey to another person, add a row of `None` values to the end of your `df`:

   ```
   df = df.append(pd.Series([None]*len(column_names), index=column_names), ignore_index=True)
   ```

   You can then edit directly the last row of `df` while asking. For example:

   ```
   sex = input('your sex: ')
   df.loc[len(df)-1, 'sex'] = sex
   ```